# Exercise $8$, Section $3.A$ - Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

I realise the following exercise isn't really something that I should have to post. But I couldn't think of a solution quickly enough. Now that I have it and I know it is correct, I just want someone else's opinion.

Exercise: Give an example of a function $\varphi : R^2 \to R $ such that $\varphi (av)=a\varphi(v)$ for all $a \in R$ and all $v \in R^2$ but $\varphi$ is not linear.

Solution: Define $\varphi : R^2\to R$ by $\varphi(x, y)=\frac {x^2} y$. Then we see that $\varphi$ satisfies homogeneity as for any $a\in R$ we have that $\frac {(ax)^2} {ay}=\frac {ax^2} y$. Thus, for any $a\in R$, we have that $\varphi(a(x, y))=a\varphi(x, y)$. We also see that $\varphi$ does not satisfy additivity as $\varphi((x, y) + (u, v))=\frac {(x + u)^2} {y + v} \ne \frac {x^2} y + \frac {u^2} {v}$ for all $(x, y), (u, v)\in R^2$.

I feel like this is correct and I check that additivity is not satisfied.

Comment: @azif00 Thanks. Yeah I was just typing it in fast and mistyped those. I will fix them now.

Comment: You have a domain problem right now.  As is your domain is defined as $\mathbb R^2$ but your function is not defined for $(x,0)\in\mathbb R^2$.  There are easy workarounds (the function need not be continuous).

Comment: @user8675309 Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make the function $\varphi $ continuous.

Let $f$ be a bounded continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$  such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)\neq 0,$ for example $f(t)=t/(1+t^2)$ or $ f(t)=\sin t.$ The function of the form $$\varphi(x,y)=\begin{cases}x\,f\left({y\over x}\right ) & x\neq 0\\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}$$ is continuous and satisfies $\varphi(ax,ay)=\varphi(x,y).$ The function $\varphi$ is not additive as $$\varphi (0,1)+\varphi (1,0)=0,\ \varphi (1,1)=f(1)\neq 0$$

Comment: Or, you could use the much simpler continuous function $\phi(x, y) = \sqrt{|xy|}$. ;-)

Comment: What about $a=-1?$  $ :($